# "inout" broke my function. What im doing wrong?

Tags: swift, function

I was reading the docs and wanted to try "inout" parameter in my function, but it doesn't seem to work as I want it to. What am I doing wrong?

```
func numbersInPow(numbers: inout [Int], powerBy: Int) -> [Int] {
    return numbers.forEach { Int(pow(Double($0), Double(powerBy))) //error
}

print(numbersInPow(numbers: &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], powerBy: 6))  //doesnt let me to pass int array in here
```

Comment: _Why_ do you want to use `inout` here?

Comment: Also I think you're looking for `map`, not `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

You can use one extra var to pass the array and no need to return an array from `numbersInPow` method as you are using inout.

Modify the function like this

```
func numbersInPow(numbers: inout [Int], powerBy: Int){
   numbers = numbers.map { Int(pow(Double($0), Double(powerBy))) }
}
```

And Use

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
numbersInPow(numbers: &arr, powerBy: 6)
print(arr) // Output : [1, 64, 729, 4096, 15625]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error sasy `Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: implicit conversion from '' to '' requires a temporary`. In your function `numbersInPow`   Swift thinks that `&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` is constants - it means `let`. Giving a constant to an in-out parameters makse no sense because of cannot be changed.

So you must modify it like

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(numbersInPow(numbers: &arr, powerBy: 6))
```